# Add a method to an exited ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array like this:

```
ArrayList<FuelData> arrValue = objrp.FuelReport(AccountID,
                    deviceID, datefrom, dateto, timezone, timefrom, timeto);
            for (int i = 0; i < arrValue.size(); i++) {
                String statusDescription = StatusCode.getDescription(AccountID,
                        arrValue.get(i).GetStatusCode(), privLabel, null);
                String detail = "Mức nhiên liệu:"
                        + Math.round(arrValue.get(i).GetFuelLevel())
                        + " l\\nQuãng đường đi được:"
                        + Math.round(arrValue.get(i).GetFuelLevel())// adding GetOdometer here
                        + " km\\nThời gian: "
                        + ConvertFromEpoch(arrValue.get(i).getTimeStamp())
                        + "\\nĐịa điểm:"
                        + GetUTF8FromNCRDecimalString(arrValue.get(i)
                                .getAddress()) + "\\nTrạng thái: "
                        + GetUTF8FromNCRDecimalString(statusDescription);

                strscr += "chartData.push({fuelLevel: "
                        + arrValue.get(i).GetFuelLevel() + ",odometerKm: "
                        + arrValue.get(i).GetOdometerKM() + ", detail:\""
                        + detail + "\"});\n";
            }
```

now I want to add this method:

```
GetOdometer(String accountID, String deviceID, String timestamp)
```

to this line: `+ Math.round(arrValue.get(i).GetFuelLevel())// adding GetOdometer here`.This method is not belong to FuelData class but in other class. Can I do this, and if can, how can I do?

Comment: This is not an `array` it is `ArrayList`

Comment: Create an instance of that other class and then use `instance.getOdometer()` to call it

Comment: @Tirath I did the same of your suggestion, but I still cannot get getOdometer()'s value

Comment: can you share the signature of getOdometer()

Comment: What you just tried also

Comment: Try reducing your code to a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (at the very last, remove all those commented-out parts).  During this process, the error might already become visible to you and if not, it is easier for us to help.

Comment: @dailammoc just curious to ask does your method has a return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `arrValue.get(i)` fetches you the object of `FuelData` class at `i`th index in the `arrValue` arraylist.

Now, if the method `getOdometer()` is defined inside `FuelData` - You should be able to access it  using the below statement

```
    arrValue.get(i).getOdometer("value1", "value2", "value3")
```

Make sure `getOdometer` method returns a string or atleast it returns something.

Also, as I noticed you mentiioned this method is not defined in `FuelData`. Then you should be fine doing the below

```
//create Instance Of This Other Class before the for loop
//then call `GetOdometer(String accountID, String deviceID, String timestamp)`
//make sure GetOdometer is returning something
//follow camel casing for naming methods
```

For example,

```
///create instance
OtherClass c = new otherClass();
for (int i = 0; i < arrValue.size(); i++) {
.
.
String detail = "Mức nhiên liệu:"
               + Math.round(arrValue.get(i).GetFuelLevel())
               + c.GetOdometer("value1", "value2", "value3")
```

Try above code change only if `GetFuelLevel` methods behavior is same for all the objects of this `OtherClass`. Otherwise move

```
OtherClass c = new otherClass();
```

inside the for loop. Let me know in the comments if it does not work.